# Webserver is fetching rather than executing CGI files

Tags: ubuntu, bugzilla

I am settings up Bugzilla for the first time, and I've been getting this error:

```
TEST-FAILED Webserver is fetching rather than executing CGI files.
Check the AddHandler statement in your httpd.conf file.
```

I've searched **a lot** of different threads, but nothing helped. The AddHandler statement seems correct. Here is my apache2.conf.

```
ScriptAlias /bugzilla/ /var/www/html/bugzilla/
<Directory /var/www/html/bugzilla>
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.cgi
AllowOverride Limit FileInfo Indexes Options
</Directory>
```

I followed this tutorial: https://bugzilla.readthedocs.org/en/5.0/installing/linux.html I am stuck on 3.2.9, where `./testserver.pl` results in the error above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something that was never mentioned in any tutorial, or any of my searches was enabling the CGI module.

```
sudo a2enmod cgi
sudo service apache2 restart
```

For reference, here is my apache2.conf:

```
Alias /bugzilla/ /var/www/html/bugzilla/
<Directory /var/www/html/bugzilla>
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.cgi
AllowOverride Limit FileInfo Indexes Options
</Directory>
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/54251/how-do-i-make-apache-run-a-cgi-instead-of-showing-the-text

Comment: http://bugzilla.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing/linux.html says: "The default Bugzilla distribution is NOT designed to be placed in a cgi-bin directory. This includes any directory which is configured using the ScriptAlias directive of Apache." So just to confirm, ScriptAlias is not the way forward :-)

Comment: I've filed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1183571 on adding "a2enmod cgi" to the docs.

Comment: HBruijn suggested ScriptAlias.

Comment: a2enmod cgi. Ficed it immediately. Everything else was properly configured. Except that piece.

Answer (score 1):

On mobile so a bit brief, but rather than an `Alias` directive try [`ScriptAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptalias) for CGI.

Comment: I changed it, but still nothing. The `./testserver.pl` command should work regardless of an alias present.